# Use method with an Activity as parameter in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter

I have an issue with my RecyclerView Adapter.
I would like to call this method in my RecyclerView Adapter class :

```
class UIManager {
   companion object {
      fun updateElem(fromActivity: Activity?)
      {
        if (fromActivity == null) { return }

        val number: TextView = fromActivity.findViewById(R.id.box)

        var chest = fromActivity.resources.getString(R.string.chests)
        if (DataManager.boxes?.size!! < 2)
            chest = fromActivity.resources.getString(R.string.chest)

        number.text = DataManager.boxes?.size?.let { "" + DataManager.boxes?.size + " " + chest } ?: "0 " + chest 
    }
   }
  }
```

Normally I could just create a method in my Adapter and pass Activity as parameter then call updateElem().

BUT I tried a lot of things and it didn't worked for me because even if I do that, I'm calling it in an override method of my Adapter, see :

```
class RecyclerAdapter(val list: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>()
{

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate((R.layout.box_elem), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.original_box)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            removeElemAt(position)
        })
    }

    fun removeElemAt(position: Int) {
        list.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size)

        // I WANT TO USE THE METHOD HERE
        // !!
        UIManager.updateElem()   <--------------
        //
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var image: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.box_elem)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Pass the activity in the constructor of RecyclerAdapter when you create it and then use that property with updateElem()

Comment: I already tried to declare a variable like this : var activity: Activity = MainActivity()  in my RecyclerAdapter then use it with updateElem() but it didn't worked. It crash here in my updateElem() :  val number: TextView = fromActivity.findViewById(R.id.box)

Comment: That's not going to work. You need something like this: class RecyclerAdapter(val context: Activity, val list: ArrayList<String>), then you can use UIManager.updateElem(activity).

Comment: Thank you so much man ! I forgot that unfortunately , hard day today ahah

Comment: @Luksprog can you make that an answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an activity reference you can always pass it to the adapter's constructor when you create it:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(val activity: Activity, val list: ArrayList<String>)
//...
```

Then you could use the activity property for the UIManager.updateElem(activity) call.